# Completability of a uniform space, metric space and topological vector space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Topological_structure)

> In particular, topological vector spaces are uniform spaces and one
> can thus talk about completeness, uniform convergence and uniform
> continuity. (This implies that every Hausdorff topological vector
> space is completely regular.[2]) The vector space operations of
> addition and scalar multiplication are actually uniformly continuous.
> Because of this, **every topological vector space can be completed** and
> is thus a dense linear subspace of a complete topological vector
> space.

1. I was wondering generally what some conditions are for a uniform
   space to be completed? I couldn't find relevant information on Wikipedia and likes.
2. Similar question for a metric space?
3. Because of what, can every topological vector space be completed?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\hat{X}$ be the completion of the TVS $(X,a,s)$ as a uniform space (as in the mentioned General Topology books). Herein $a$ and $s$ denote the vector space addition and scalar multiplication. As $a$ and $s$ are *uniformly continuous* maps, they have a unique uniformly continuous extension $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{s}$ from $\hat{X} \times \hat{X}$ resp. $K \times \hat{X}$ to $\hat{X}$ where $K$ denotes the underlying field.

Now you can easily verify that $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{s}$ fulfill the vector space axioms on $\hat{X}$. This is the key argument: The purely non-algebraic uniform completion of a TVS preserves the algebraic vector space structure and turns the uniform completion into a complete TVS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Every uniform space has a unique (up to uniform isomorphism) completion.
2. Every metric space can be completed (this is a standard result in analysis).

The book General Topology by Engelking has a whole section on uniform spaces if you are interested in seeing the proofs.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Yes, I am interested in where the completability results for uniform spaces, metric spaces and TVS are in that book and other references? I just searched that book, but might miss things.

Comment: Kelley, *General Topology* also has a chapter on uniform spaces.  [edited the answer to correct spelling Engelking]